# Element that scroll vertically and horizontally in android

Tags: android

In (Android) Suggest me that to use which Element so that i can scroll the data on the screen in vertical direction when user  is in portrait orientation and able to scroll horizontally when user is in landscape orientation.

And tell if i have to make it customized element.

Comment: I Got the answer its a valid one it not to be closed by saying ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad....

Comment: Use the Simple concept like use the Scroll and Horizontal Scroll and I  have done with that my problem is solved....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must detect which display orientation you have. For that use layout detection or create two layouts (one for horizontal and second for vertical view) and use ScrollView

ScrollView only supports vertical scrolling. For horizontal scrolling, use HorizontalScrollView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScrollView` as container for your layout elements: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: I am using a layout-land and layout-port for the tablet layouts.If i change any single then the other could not work.I am having a requirement that i have to implement it into the same way.

Comment: Then your code is broken most likely. Layout files are not dependent on each other (unless you made so). Having `layout-land/foo.xml` and `layout/foo.xml` is not a problem. Both can be **totally** different

Comment: And also use the Horizontal ScrollView for Horizontal Scroll

Answer (score 0):

Use `ScrollView` to scroll whole screen in vertical direction

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <your items>
</ScrollView>
```

Use `HorizontalScrollView` for horizontal scrolling,

[How to use HorizontalScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021993/how-to-use-horizontalscrollview)

and yes, you need two different layout for portrait and landscape and put in different folder

Use `ListView` to get a scrolling list of items like strings etc